# The provided location 'francecentral' is not available for resource type

Tags: azure-container-service

Describe the bug
I am following instructions at
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-quick-task
When I issue the following command on a resource group in France Central Region

az container create ............

I get

The provided location 'francecentral' is not available for resource type 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups'. List of available regions for the resource type is
'westcentralus,westus,eastus,westeurope,westus2,northeurope,southeastasia,eastus2,centralus,australiaeast,uksouth,southcentralus,centralindia,brazilsouth,southindia,northcentralus,eastasia,canadacentral,japaneast,koreacentral'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xukV0.jpg)

Is it normal?

Any relevant environment information

Azure Shell/ Bash
5/25/2020, 6:26 PM GMT+2
Registry = sierac.azurecr.io
image names = helloacrtasks:v1
Additional context
Add any other context about the problem here.
I opened a thread with full details at https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/406

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal that cloud providers roll out services to different regions at different times.

Check the [Products available by region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=container-instances&regions=france-central,france-south) in the Azure documentation. The service you are trying to launch is currently in state `Future availability` `GA expected Q2 2020`.

There is not too much you can do about that. You could try to reach out to their support or sales and try to get access to a preview.